# How to count how the number of elements stored in a vector which is stored in a map

Tags: c++

I have four static vectors. In my .cpp file (not my .h file!) I define these vector as such:

```
     std::vector<Object*> ClassA::vecA;
     std::vector<Object*> ClassA::vecB;
     std::vector<Object*> ClassA::vecC;
     std::vector<Object*> ClassA::vecD;
```

Then I populate each of these vectors with a number of objects of type Object.

Next I create a map:

```
     std::map<std::string, std::vector<Object*> > cntr;
```

I populate this map with the vectors from above and a string as a Key for each vector.

The question is, how do I access the vectors in the map to find out the number of elements they contain. I have tried:

```
     for (it = Cntr.begin(); it != Cntr.end(); it++) 
     {
        if (it->first != token)
        {
         std::cout << it->first << std::endl;

            int i = (it->second).size();

            std::cout << "SIZE: "      << i << std::endl;

        }
    }
```

However i always gives me the value of 1. What is the correct approach?

Comment: The code looks fine (except that `Cntr` in the loop should be `cntr` instead, and `int i` should be `size_t i` or even `std::vector<Object*>::size_type` instead). But in any case, you did not show how you are populating the vectors or the map.  `size()` does not lie, though.  If it returns 1, then you really have only 1 element in the vector.

Answer (score 2):

First off you need to set the iterator to point to an valid element of the map.  When you do

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Object*>>::iterator Class::it;
int size = it->second.size();
```

`it` doesn't point to anything so using it is undefined behavior.  What you can do though is use

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Object*>>::iterator Class::it;
it = cntr.begin();
int size = it->second.size();
```

Which now gives you the size of the first vector in the map.

If you want to get all of the sizes then you will need to iterate through the map.  You can do this with a nice ranged based for loop like

```
for (const auto & elem : cntr) // get a const reference to each pair
    std::cout << elem.second.size();
```

Comment: I should have mention that this is conducted int a for-loop:

Comment: @MagnusHimmler Then you will need to provide a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 0):

NathanOliver's answer should work if you have C++11. If you don't, you can try this, with a typedef to make the code clear:

```
typedef std::vector<Object*> MypObjVec;
typedef std::map<std::string, MypObjVec> MyMap;

MyMap::iterator Class::it = cntr.begin();
const MyMap::iterator Class::it_end = cntr.end();

for(; it!=it_end ; ++it)
{
   std::cout<< it->second.size() << std::endl;
}
```